# error: use of 'auto' in lambda parameter declaration only available with -std=c++1y or -std=gnu++1y [-Werror]

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, auto

I have a template function that takes and puts it into output stream without worrying about the type. This is a C++ 14 compatible code which has auto as params to lambda. But, I need my compiler settings to be C++ 11. What changes do I make to resolve this so that it works with C++ 11 too.

Here is my code

```
template<class... Args >
std::string build_message( Args&&... args )
{

    auto aPrintImplFn = [](auto& os, auto&& ... ts) {
        // expression (void) just to suppress the unused variable warning
        (void)std::initializer_list<char> { (os << ts, '0')... };
    };

    std::ostringstream out;
    aPrintImplFn(out, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    return out.str();
}
```

Comment: Spell out the lambda parameters: `auto aPrintImplFn = [](std::ostringstream& os,Args&& ... ts) {...}`

Comment: I guess it's worth noting that `aPrintImplFn` could be inlined entirely; I don't see any reason to have that be a separate function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `auto` to the explicit type, as follows

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
template<class... Args >
std::string build_message( Args&&... args )
{

    auto aPrintImplFn = [](std::ostringstream & os, Args&& ... ts) {
        // expression (void) just to suppress the unused variable warning
        (void)std::initializer_list<char> { (os << ts, '0')... };
    };

    std::ostringstream out;
    aPrintImplFn(out, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    return out.str();
}
```